# How remove duplicates in same file and with if condition?

Tags: shell-script, perl

`INPUT FILE: has all these values without header:`
`customer ID, code,    start_date, end_date 
 124343,     DCW,     2015-07-06, 2016-08-03
 235432,     ABC,     2015-04-26, NULL
 235432,     ABC,     2015-04-26, 2015-06-20
3242342,     ABC,     2015-08-02, 2015-07-28
2332434,     DCW,     2015-02-09, 2015-06-23
2332434,     DCW,     2015-06-23, NULL`

1. when customer ID & code has more than 1 record in file with value in end_date and null in end_date then only records with null end_date.
2. when customer ID & code has more than 1 record with start_date, end_date and start_date equal to end_date for the first record then only record with null end_date or future date than today's date.
3. when customer ID & code has more than 1 records in file with two start dates then only consider max date value.
   Required Output
   Only one record for customer ID & code is required
   `customer ID, code, start_date, end_date
   124343,     DCW,    2015-07-06, 2016-08-03
   235432,     ABC,   2015-04-26, null
   3242342,     ABC,    2015-08-02, 2015-07-28
   2332434,     DCW,   2015-06-23, null`

Comment: Have you made an attempt? Is this homework?

Comment: Not HW. Have got awk to work to find duplicates for first three rows in a file then now date func compare is issue not sure how to convert string to date.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '
{
if($1$2==cust){
    if(startdate<$3){
        custline=$0
        startdate=$3
        enddate=$4
        next
    }
    if(startdate==$3 && enddate<$4){
        custline=$0
        startdate=$3
        enddate=$4
        next
    }
}else{
    if(custline!=""){ print custline }
    custline=$0
    cust=$1$2
    startdate=$3
    enddate=$4
    next
}
}END{print custline}' inputfile
```

Assumptions made:
1. Possible to have a customer with 2 or more "codes" and that it is desirable to see these as separate entries.
2. Date format will stay as shown in the samples: YYYY-MM-DD